Unable to add Google Analytics to an existing application which doesn't already have AD_ID permission in manifest file
I have an existing app on Play Store, including an internal testing and closed testing track. I want to add Google Analytics, and therefore have added the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission to my manifest file. When I try to submit a version to internal testing I get an error saying I must update the advertising ID declaration:
This release includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission but your declaration on Play Console says your app doesn't use advertising ID.

You must update your advertising ID declaration.

Updating the advertising ID declaration gives another error, saying an active artifact doesn't include the manifest permission:
Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.


If you don't include this permission in your manifest file, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out. This may break your advertising and analytics use cases, and cause loss of revenue.

You can remove these errors by updating your advertising ID declaration


Apps that target Android 13 (API 33) without the AD_ID permission will have their advertising identifier zeroed out. This may impact advertising and analytics use-cases.

I assume this is because my existing production version doesn't have the updated manifest. How can I update my manifest file when doing so requires an updated advertising ID declaration, but updating the advertising ID declaration requires an updated manifest file?
For reference, here is my manifest file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>  <!-- Added this line -->
...
</manifest>

